# Writing array in Firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to write this to my Firebase

Parent

--0 : John

--1 : Tim

--2 : Sam

--3 : Ben

I am doing this

```
String[] names = {"John","Tim","Sam","Ben"};
myFirebaseRef.setValue(names);
```

And it is not writing anything.

It works using the Chrome Console for Firebase.

Isn't this the way you write an array to firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `.setValue()` method needs a `List` rather than an `Array`.

> The [native types accepted by this method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_setValue) for the value correspond to
>   the JSON types: Boolean, Long, Double, Map, String, Object, List, Object...

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
String[] names = {"John","Tim","Sam","Ben"};
List nameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
// Now set value with new nameList
ref.setValue(nameList);
```

But, I recommend using a `Map` instead of a `List`. Rather than having an index based key (1,2,3...), you could use the name as the key so it's easier to retrieve.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
HashMap<String, String> names = new HashMap()<String, String>;
names.put("John", "John");
names.put("Tim", "Tim");
names.put("Sam", "Sam");
names.put("Ben", "Ben");
ref.setValue(names);
```

And now if you want to retrieve the data, you just need to know the name.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
Firebase johnRef = ref.child("john");
johnRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       System.out.println(snapshot.value); // the String "John"
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

[Read the Firebase docs for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will this save it as 0: John, 1: Tim... or John:John, Tim:Tim...?

Comment: This answer contained most of the information that I have been looking for. Thanks David!

Comment: Hello @David East
Thank you for your answer, i need some more information regarding array in firebase realtime database,
i would like to perform delete String and add new to String to existing array

Comment: This answer just saved my job!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Java, but for web application, you can use something as follows:

I wanted to create a reusable function to add/save any object under a root node **(even if that has an array of data at any level within the object)**. So I came up with this. (I am not sure if conforms to the best practices, but it worked pretty smooth)

```
    SaveWholeData: function(sKey, oVal, bGenKey) {
        bGenKey = bGenKey === undefined ? true: bGenKey;
        var oOriginalProperty = angular.copy(oVal);
        for (var property in oVal) {
            if (oVal.hasOwnProperty(property) && oVal[property] instanceof Array) {
                console.log(property);
                oVal[property] = "$|$";
            }
        }
        var sOwnRef = SaveDataByKey(sKey, oVal, bGenKey);
        for (var property in oVal) {
            if (oVal.hasOwnProperty(property) && oVal[property] === "$|$") {
                oVal[property] = oOriginalProperty[property];
                var updatedReference = sOwnRef + "/" + property;
               SaveWholeData(updatedReference, oVal[property], false);
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    SaveDataByKey: function(sKey, oVal, bGenKey) {
        if (bGenKey) {
            var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref(sKey).push().key;
            oVal.genKey = newPostKey;
            firebase.database().ref(sKey).child(newPostKey).set(oVal);
            return sKey + "/" + newPostKey;
        }else{
            firebase.database().ref(sKey).set(oVal);
            return sKey;
        }
    }
```

So to **add new user** under root `users`, you call:

```
SaveWholeData("users", oUserInfo, true);
```

and to **update existing user**:

```
SaveWholeData("users"+"/"+ oUserInfo.genKey, oUserInfo, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List sendingList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(SendingArray));
```

In case of any error, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will correct it depending on you version of android studio